# Ubuntu 14.04 won't boot after installing CUDA 7

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, cuda

I got a laptop (Dell Precision M4700) with a Quadro K2000M. I have two drives, one for Windows 7 and one for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS followed by an upgrade to 14.04.2, and then immediately followed by an installation of CUDA 7, subsequent boots into Ubuntu are unsuccessful: it basically hangs at the purple screen with Ubuntu and the five dots underneath - every time.

I got the latest deb from the [Nvidia downloads](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

Then I did:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

then reboot and it hangs... every time.

I know there are some folks posting similar issues, but none of these posts have a solution that worked for me.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate - it's not a question of "how", as  I am following the instructions from NVIDIA to the letter ( http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions ). I have done it twice just to be sure, each time starting from a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS install, but to no avail.

Comment: How many GPU's do you have?  Last time I looked, you needed more then one and for all of them to be identical...

Comment: It turns out that my laptop is has a hybrid graphics system:  I have a DELL Precision M4700 with an integrated Intel graphics processor and then I have a "discrete" graphics processor which is an NVIDIA Quadro K2000M. I learned today that perhaps the issues I got has to do with the fact that it's a hybrid system that uses Optimus technology - I am still learning up on this as I am not sure yet how this impacts NVIDIA driver installations.

Comment: I've got a hybrid system too and have turned it off: I normally run in Intel mode to save battery and have a cool system, unless I need the HDMI port or want to do some serious gaming: then I reboot, go to the BIOS and run in pure NVidia mode...  I 've never been able to make CUDA run on this system (laptop). Last time I tried with a hardcore desktop, it wouldn't work on even 2 NVIDIA GPUs unless the hardware chipset was identical.

Comment: I have discovered something: I am always able to completely boot and log into Ubuntu when I select, in GRUB, "Advanced Options for Ubuntu", and then select Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-30-generic (note that my default is Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-38-generic). Once I am logged in, none of the CUDA stuff works. But when I reboot again. and then this time in the default version (3.16.0-38-generic), then it actually boots completely and let's me log in, and all the CUDA stuff works (i.e. the samples). So I have to do this flip-flop alternate booting scheme as described above

Answer (score 0):

it happened exactly the same for me.
as you said Galto, that also helps me, on boot to choose the other generic version then the default, this one i can login with, and then when i restart it again, it works normally.
but i have to do it every time, if i'll restart it again it will get stuck, i will need to do the same generic+restart option for it to work.
sounds ridiculous but it works.

Comment: I tried everything, including these instructions: ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/349.16/README/optimus.html but to no avail. I am hoping someone on this list might have an answer sometime in the near future - in the mean time, double boots will get me going. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same issue with a Dell Precision M6800 with a Quadro K5100M GPU, running Ubuntu 14.04.  I stumbled upon the the double reboot solution that @Galto mentioned by accident, but it seems to work reliably. I first reboot using the original generic kernel, 3.13.0-32-generic (without the CUDA packages installed), and then (without even needing to log in completely) I am able to reboot into the latest kernel (with CUDA installed). If I try boot directly to the latest kernel without the first step, the Ubuntu boot sequence just hangs without reaching the login screen... 
a "hacky" solution, but workable for now...